# Overriding a method of generic super class that returns T

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, subclass

Super class looks this :

```
public class DomainRepository<T> {
    public DomainRepository(Class genericType) {
        this.genericType = genericType;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public T get(final long id) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(genericType, id);
    }
}
```

Sub class looks like this

```
public class FooRepository extends DomainRepository<Foo> {
    public FooRepository(){
        super(Foo.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Foo get(final Long id) { //blah blah
```

But my IDE highlights error on @Override annoation sayign method does override anything ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like `Long` and `long` mismatch.

Comment: ffs. Great thanks a lot, thats got rid of the error. Will accept when allowed to.